# Flowcode Transmits UDP but Unsuccssefully read by the server

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I'm using Flowcode technology to program a micro controller 16F877A.

from flowcode i'm sending 3 bytes UDP packets to a server listening on port 23456.

the problem is that the server never receives those packets. i used wireshark for tracing and it was able to detect the 3 bytes and its content.

below is my server code using c#

```
const int port_number=23456;
TcpListener server=new TcpListener( IPAddress.Any ,port_number);
Socket soc;
NetworkStream s; 
bool exit=false; 
Thread mythread;
```

thread code is here

```
void method()
    {
        try
        {
            server.Start();
            soc = server.AcceptSocket();
            s = new NetworkStream(soc);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
            textBox1.Text += sr.ReadLine();
            if(soc.Connected==true && exit==false)
            method();                   
        }
        catch(Exception es)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}",es.Message);
        }

    }
```

do you think i need to change anything to be able to read those 3 bytes and process them.

i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a TcpListening, but you are sending UDP packets? Try the UDPClient class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx

**Edit** 
To elaborate a little bit. A TCP Client will never receive UDP packets, since TCP and UDP are two separate protocols at the socket level. The socket will see you are listening for a TCP connection, it will receive the UDP datagram, see no listeners, and throw it away.

Comment: thanks, by using your note and the link below i was able to successfully solve my problem http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/92846ccb-fad3-469a-baf7-bb153ce2d82b/